# How do I get the name of the NetSuite company using SuiteQL?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

Is it possible to get company info (name, address, timezone, etc) from NetSuite using SuiteQL? I can't find any references to it in the docs.

Comment: Here's a link to support Documentation for Executing SuiteQL Queries Through REST Web Services: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf#page=65&zoom=100,120,669

Comment: @Martha that doesn't answer the question. What select statement do I use to get the company info?

Answer (score -1):

You could do this by making a post request to the suiteql endpoint and including the requested information in the raw body of the request.

Example:

POST request to:
https://{yourNetsuiteCompanyID}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql

```
Body:
{
    "q": "select customer.CompanyName, customer.id, customer.name from 
          Customer"
}
```

This request would give me the company name and internal company id. I can also rename these fields as I would in SQL.

Comment: Similarly to sql you can also select all contents from the table to get an idea of the columns available using the following query:     "q": "select * from Customer"

Comment: Not customer.companyName, I need the name of the NetSuite Company Name, i.e. what you would see if you went to Setup -> Company -> Company Information